# MVC - Best pattern (UoW + Repositories + Services + DI)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I've been doing mvc for some time, but it's my first contact with DI.

I started a new project with Ninject which seems pretty simple and easy to understand, however almost every tutorial I saw has UoW, Repositories and Services.

What I understand is that:

- **Repositories** - Abstract Layer for interactions with EF / MongoDB / XML / Whatever may be a database (CRUD Operations)
- **UoW** - Set of operations that correlate together, it may use *N* repositories to perform tasks that will be used in *Controllers*
- **Services** I don't really get the point of this, it seems just one more step as it uses multiple **UoW**'s to perform "more tasks"? I'm lost in this one.

Ok, it took me some time to "eat" the *Repository* thing since i prefer to pass the *EF Context* trough the *UoW*.

Is it ok if i forget the Repository and just use the context? Or is it used for any `Unit Test` task?

What's the *Service*'s usage? 
Since I may perform every actions/tasks inside *UoW* and then call it inside the controllers.

Is there any better set of patterns to use?

Comment: Primary opinon based, vote to close

Comment: Objection. It isn't opinion based, there is only one true correct statement about this. It may exist multiple "almost correct" statements.
What's the use for stackoverflow if not asking for better way's of implementations. Its not all about code

Comment: It might be good to skip the whole 'services' thing and move on directly to [handlers](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are very common and you might be talking about either, I'm going to give a brief explanation about each.

**Domain Services:** When you have an entity and you start to push logic into it, you might get to a point where part of the logic doesn't really belong to that entity, so you create a Domain Service to abstract this logic away. An example would be:

```
public class Shipment
{
    ...
    public void CalculateFee(IFeeCalculatorService feeCalculatorService)
    {
        ... Any additional and entity relevant logic for fee calculation can be here as well.
        this.Fee = feeCalculatorService.Calculate();
    }
    ...
}
```

**Application Services:** These are the services that you will be calling from your controllers to encapsulate the operations needed for a specific task. Let's say you have a controller to receive a friendship request approval or rejection. Your Application Service should receive enough data to be able to:

- Find the friendship request domain entity
- Call its approve or reject method
- Call the methods to persist that change back to the database
- Return relevant information to the controller

**Infrastructure Services:** These services will abstract the logic that is not related to the business, but related to how the application works. An example would be a service to validate security tokens received on your requests, or to perform logging activities.

Comment: Ok that seems what I was looking for when I asked for services.

Answer (score 1):

EFs DBContext already implements both the UoW and Repository patterns, so yiu have no benefit of implementing those again in yiur own code.

Services are a way to abstract business logic so it can be reused

Comment: Ok, i see so i just need to use Services? I'm using UoW as if it was the Service layer.

Comment: Be careful in describe in general that it "have no benefit" to use an UoW on top of what EF supplies. It all depends on context. I often find it quite useful myself to prevent my application code from having a dependency on EF (as the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) prescribes) and I do use repositories and Unit of Work for this.

Comment: @Steven I am repetedly seeing people implement half-baked UoW and repository patterns on top of EF without any good reason because "that's how you do it". So yes, if you need to read this thread you have no benefit from them. On the contrary your own implementations are likely to make it **harder** for you to use what EF already provides for free.

Comment: The only reason I see on using Repositories is that you may add some pre-commit methods before adding an object to the DB, maybe to change some properties or similar. But I didn't see a single tutorial about DI without Repositories and UoW

Comment: @Leandro You can do a lot in that regard by overriding SaveChanges() and SaveChangesAsync(...) in your DbContext.

Comment: Yes you can, but still that would be hit in every model. If you were to change a property in a specific model then it would be the more clean if you have this repositories. But it doesn't seem to be a true reason to use it...